# Alter year in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, date

We have a column called date which is type datetime in a MySQL table, in which accidentally rows got added with the wrong year in.

E.g. 2015-09-30 23:57:29 instead of 2014-09-30 23:57:29

Is there a quick to change all these dates to the correct year? I was thinking of using date_sub but wasn't sure of the exact syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET field = DATE_SUB(field, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE YEAR(field) = 2015
```

I suppose you want to change all rows with year 2015. If your condition is different, please feel free to change it

Comment: This would also change the 2014 to 2013

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: in "yourcondition" he can add about year = 2015. Now I update my answer